# Cannot resolve constructor 'Intent(xxxx.xx.java.lang.thread.Class<com.practice.MainActivity>)'

Tags: android, android-intent

/*  This is my launcher activity basically a splash screen which will wait for 5 sec but there is some problem with the intent..pls help
*/

```
package com.hfad.practice;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class Starting extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void start()
    {
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_starting);

        Thread timer=new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                      sleep(5000);
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally
                {

                    Intent intent=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class); /*
                    here it is showing an error thats mentioned in the title*/
                    startActivity(intent);


                }


            }

        };
        timer.start();
    }


}
```

Comment: Your title cites `MainActivity`. Your source cites `Starting`. Which is it?

Comment: it is starting activity which is calling the mainActivity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
```

with

```
Intent intent=new Intent(Starting.this,MainActivity.class);
```

in your case `this` refers to the `Thread` subclass, while the first argument of `Intent` is a `Context` object

Comment: Thanxxx it worked!!but i took the course in udacity there we just wrote this

Comment: has anything changed?

Comment: no, it didn't changed. It is either a mistake in the class or you misread their instruction/explanation.

Comment: ohh okay just a doubt ,, i just rechecked my previous code there i created an intent in a user defined function there only writitng this in first argument worked...

Comment: public void startnew()
    {
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,Splash.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

Comment: `this` refers to the current object. In your question `this` refers to the `Thread` subclass and not to the `Activity` (which extends `Context`). If it was working before it is because, `this` was referring to a `Context`